# Autocad 2013 : edit object xData? - no or little coding experience

Tags: .net, autocad

I'm using autocad 2013 and have drawings with lots of entities with xdata attached. (Always a text-string)

What I found in the xdata was this :

- Code 1000, ASCII string: MQLEAC
- Code 1000, ASCII string: 28661,1512

so, there are 2 strings I suppose. is it possible to change the name of "MQLEAC" into something else? and repeat that for all similar xdata on the drawing?

easiest would be something like find-replace, or a list before->after that I can enter.

even command - inputs would be alright.

I was hoping the xdata would be stored somewhere accessible, so i could just edit text somewhere.. but that seems impossible?

Any help is welcome.
I don't have software to code on my working spot.. so the stuff I found about .NET is kinda hard to do I guess? might not be able to install it here.

Answer (score 0):

`XDATA` is attached to *each* entity. You have to open the `XDATA` object and iterate all of the values inside it. I have done this several times with VBA (not .Net languages).

That said, I don't think that anyone is going to provide a **direct solution** to your problem. Ideally you need to provide us an example of what you have tried out so far. Besides, there are different .Net languages so we would need to know which you are using.

That said, you might not have to re-invent the wheel here. If all you want to do is find/replace XDATA then there is a tool available:

[image: Search and replace XDATA]

I *think* you have purchase just the **commands** that you require from them. See http://www.4d-technologies.com/.

If you intend on still writing your own application to do this then there are plenty of **tutorials**. For example, this one is for writing `XDATA`:

http://www.through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/04/adding_xdata_to.html